# random.shuffle(points).take(k) in Python

Tags: python, scala, random, shuffle

What is the equivalent of this Scala line in Python?

```
 random.shuffle(points).take(k)
```

I don't seem to find the take method for shuffle in Python

Comment: What does `take` do in `scala`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick `k` random elements out of an iterable using `sample`

```
import random

return random.sample(points, k)
```

Also, random has `shuffle` (but it is mutating) and you can use slices instead of `take`:

```
copy = points[:]
random.shuffle(copy)
return copy[:k]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) is one option you have, from numpy, to randomly shuffle `points`

```
np.random.shuffle()
```

[This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) is one option you have, from numpy, to randomly choose `k` out of `points`

```
np.random.choice(points, size=k)
```

Comment: Where is the take method? I see the shuffle in Python not take

Comment: please write the complete code in answers because links can change

Comment: I referred you to the link because it is official numpy documentation, and if they decide to update the function, the link still points to the correct version, and not something deprecated

Comment: If you are trying to achieve the following:
"Shuffle `points` and then choose `k` out of them randomly" you can use the following:
    
    `np.random.shuffle(points)`
    `np.random.choice(points, size=k)`

Comment: @SanyamMehra: That doesn't work. `np.random.choice(points, size=k)` does choice with replacement, so repeated values are possible. That's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I agree the default behavior is with replacement, but it gives the flexibility to the user by simply adding the keyword `replace=False`. You can refer to the documentation in the link I had shared earlier for more info.

`np.random.choice(points, size=k, replace=False)`

Comment: @SanyamMehra: You should probably include that information in your answer, then, instead of giving something which doesn't do what the OP asked for.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I appreciate you sharing your concern for the OPs interests. I had shared the link because all the required information was very readily accessible there, but including the same in the post explicitly in the post would have been a better idea, I agree.